# Use Ipython-sql with snowflake and externalbrowser authenticator

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, ipython-sql

in my jupyter notebook I connect to snowflake with an externalbrowser auth like so:

```
conn = snowflake.connector.connect(
user='<my user>',
authenticator='externalbrowser',
account='<my account>',
warehouse='<the warehouse>')
```

this opens an external browser to auth and after that works fine with pandas read sql:

```
pd.read_sql('<a query>', conn)
```

want to use it with ipython sql, but when I try:

```
%sql snowflake://conn.user@conn.account
```

I get:

```
snowflake.connector.errors.ProgrammingError) Password is empty
```

well I don't have one :)
any ideas how to pass this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IPython-sql connection strings are [SQLAlchemy URL](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/engines.html#database-urls) standard, therefore you can do the following:

```
%load_ext sql
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from snowflake.sqlalchemy import URL

engine = create_engine(URL(
    account = '<account>',
    user = '<user>',
    database = 'testdb',
    schema = 'public',
    warehouse = '<wh>',
    role='public',
    authenticator='externalbrowser'
))
connection = engine.connect()
```

This would open the external browser for authentication.

Comment: it seems you still need to take the actual url string (output of the URL(...) fumc), but other than that using URL() solves the problem

Comment: @Ezer K: I have the same question as you. After establishing the connection as suggested by Sergiu, what was the next step to be able to run a query using %sql rather than pd.read_sql?

Comment: **pre op:** pip install ipython-sql
**1st cell:** %load_ext sql
**2nd cell:** %sql snowflake://<user>:@<account>/?authenticator=externalbrowser&warehouse=<warehouse>
**3rd cell:** %sql select current_time (just an example)

Comment: @Ezer K: Thanks for this. It is working for me now.

Comment: This is great! You can try `pip install jupysql` as it has more features like visualizing the data and in-memory data. It also has bug fixes that are still missing in `ipython-sql`. Moreover it allows you to set multiple connection engines, and maintain it, so you wouldn't need to hardcode the connection string in your notebook.