# Use ipython with Snowflake and external browser authenticator

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am able to establish a connection to snowflake from jupyter using the code snippet below.
[image: Code to establish the connection]

After this, I want to run sql queries using %sql rather than pandas. To do so, I understand I need to run code on these lines.

```
%sql snowflake://connection.user@connection.account
```

This generates an error.

```
(snowflake.connector.errors.ProgrammingError) 251006: Password is empty
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/f405)
Connection info needed in SQLAlchemy format, example:
               postgresql://username:password@hostname/dbname
               or an existing connection: dict_keys(['sqlite://'])
```

After establishing the connection, what do I do so that I can run queries using %sql?

Comment: This has been answered before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69894430/use-ipython-sql-with-snowflake-and-externalbrowser-authenticator)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use Ipython-sql with snowflake and externalbrowser authenticator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69894430/use-ipython-sql-with-snowflake-and-externalbrowser-authenticator)

Comment: This [Link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69894430/use-ipython-sql-with-snowflake-and-externalbrowser-authenticator) answers my question now after the comment yesterday by Ezer K. I was stuck at the last step.